# MySQL import and export data without update on insert

Tags: mysql, migration

I have a table that updates a timestamp column on every insert. This timestamp is indexed uniquely with a few other columns and I am unable to import this table. I guess the mysql dump/import inserts each row and some of the timestamps overlap because they are updated to the current timestamp. Is there a way to import and ignore the on update: current_timestamp() function that I have?

Answer (score 1):

A unique timestamp is a mistake waiting to happen.

If there is also an `AUTO_INCREMENT id`, you can do this:

```
PRIMARY KEY(timestamp, id),
INDEX(id)
```

Then dups are not possible.

Comment: "A unique timestamp is a mistake waiting to happen." lulz.